# Use <figure> element for icons? html5

Tags: html

It is semantically correct to use the figure element for icons like this:

```
<figure class="icon clouds"></figure>
```

This represents a icon aside a nav item.

Comment: It's never semantically correct to have an *empty* element. @snaderss: What do you base your claim upon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no its definitely not: http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/

> The figure element represents a unit of content, optionally with a
>   caption, **that is self-contained**, that is typically referenced as a
>   single unit from the main flow of the document, and that can be moved
>   away from the main flow of the document without affecting the
>   document’s meaning. W3C Specification

you can't remove it from the flow of the document. It its not next to the navigation point, it makes no more sense.

Just use a span or a :before pseudo element.